# Test login with protractor on a non angular page

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to use protractor for e2e testing but first I need to login on a non-angular page. I try to directly use the webDriver as indicated [here](http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Protractor_Testing_With_Angular_And_Non_Angular_Sites/) but it fails.

My e2e test:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {

  it('should prompt the login page', function() {
    browser.get('/');
    expect(browser.driver.find(By.id('user_password')));
  });

});
```

My logs:

```
Running "protractor:all" (protractor) task
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
F

Failures:

  1) angularjs homepage should prompt the login page
   Message:
     TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'find'
```

Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use

```
browser.driver.get
```

instead of browser.get for Non-Angular pages. Also, you need to set

```
browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true in the beforeEach() function
```

I have added a page for non-angular pages. You can refer to the same:
https://github.com/sakshisingla/Protractor-Non-Angular-Tests/wiki/Creating-test-scripts-using-Protractor-for-non-angular-application

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the protractor website:

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/faq

under **How do I deal with my log-in page?**

Comment: I am not sure I understand this bit (on the withLoginConf.js on the link you provided): isn't there something missing here ?
--->  return /index/.test(url);

Answer (score 0):

For a non angular page, first use this

> ```
> browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
> ```

The above line will tell protractor that it's not an angular page, and you can perform any action on your non-angular page. Now when you are done, and want to move to an angular page use

> ```
> browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
> ```