# Can a Knockout app be tested with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm working on a web page that uses Knockout. I set up Protractor after seeing [this post about using Protractor on non-Angular pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536933/test-login-with-protractor-on-a-non-angular-page), but it doesn't seem like Protractor can 'see' any elements that are part of a KO component.

```
describe('a simple test', function () {
  it('works', function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('profile');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Title');  // this passes (outside KO)

    expect(element(by.id('ko-component')).getText()).toEqual('Hello World!'); // this fails (inside KO)
  });
});
```

The second assertion results in this error, even though the element is definitely in the HTML.

```
Message:
 NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("ko-component")
```

If I can't use Protractor, then suggestions for other e2e testing frameworks are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`protractor` is basically a wrapper around `WedDriverJS` (javascript selenium bindings). `protractor` makes testing AngularJS page easier and more natural, knowing when angular is settled and a page is ready to be interacted with and introducing several angular-specific locators.

In other words, you can definitely test `knockout` pages with `protractor`. In this case, you need to [explicitly wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) until the `ko-component` element is present by using `presenceOf` [Expected Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var e = element(by.id('ko-component'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(e), 10000);

expect(e.getText()).toEqual('Hello World!');
```